# SQL SERVER SELECT COLUMN JSON ARRAY

Tags: sql-server, query

I have a json in column of **table** SQL Server:

```
{
    "_id":{
       "$oid":"61ccdc232d1e0a844149faba"
    },
    "report":{
       "description":"test abc",      
       "involved":[
          {
             "id":7313,
             "person":{
                "numberID":"1234",
                "fullName":"Marcos Yone ",
                "parents":{
                   "nameMother":"Maria sanches",
                   "nameFather":"Jorge Andre"
                }
             }
          },
          {
             "id":70213,
             "person":{
                "numberID":"8765",
                "fullName":"Isabel Souza ",
                "parents":{
                   "nameMother":"Luiza Santile",
                   "nameFather":"Luiz Souza"
                }
             }
          }
       ]
    }
 }
```

I'm trying to do a query for return this select

| _id | id | numberID | fullName | nameFather |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 61ccdc232d1e0a844149faba | 7313 | 1234 | Marcos Yone | Jorge Andre |
| 61ccdc232d1e0a844149faba | 70213 | 8765 | Isabel Souza | Luiz Souza |

There may be **more values** in the array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given:

```
DECLARE @T table 
(
    j nvarchar(max) NOT NULL
);

INSERT @T 
    (j) 
VALUES 
    (
    N'
    {
        "_id":{
           "$oid":"61ccdc232d1e0a844149faba"
        },
        "report":{
           "description":"test abc",      
           "involved":[
              {
                 "id":7313,
                 "person":{
                    "numberID":"1234",
                    "fullName":"Marcos Yone ",
                    "parents":{
                       "nameMother":"Maria sanches",
                       "nameFather":"Jorge Andre"
                    }
                 }
              },
              {
                 "id":70213,
                 "person":{
                    "numberID":"8765",
                    "fullName":"Isabel Souza ",
                    "parents":{
                       "nameMother":"Luiza Santile",
                       "nameFather":"Luiz Souza"
                    }
                 }
              }
           ]
        }
     }
    '
    );
```

The following produces the output specified:

```
SELECT 
    _id = JSON_VALUE(T.j, '$._id."$oid"'),
    OJ.id, 
    OJ.numberID, 
    OJ.fullName, 
    OJ.nameFather 
FROM @T AS T
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(T.j, '$.report.involved')
    WITH
    (
        id          integer         '$.id',
        numberID    integer         '$.person.numberID',
        fullName    nvarchar(50)    '$.person.fullName',
        nameFather  nvarchar(50)    '$.person.parents.nameFather'
    )
    AS OJ;
```

| _id | id | numberID | fullName | nameFather |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 61ccdc232d1e0a844149faba | 7313 | 1234 | Marcos Yone | Jorge Andre |
| 61ccdc232d1e0a844149faba | 70213 | 8765 | Isabel Souza | Luiz Souza |

[*db<>fiddle*](https://dbfiddle.uk/8YnJi7YH) demo